# All 2 cells in the DGV are updated with the same data. It seems to me that the threads have mixed up

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to update a DataGridView in a C# Winform. Suppose there are just 2 cells in this DGV.

```
public void getMarketDataForAllStocks()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => getMarketData("AAPL"));
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => getMarketData("GOOG"));
    thread2.IsBackground = true;
    thread2.Start();
}
```

getMarketData() is a method that makes a TCP connection and gets a stream.

Upon receiving the stream from the connection, it will update all cells in the DGV with the data (from the stream).

My problem is, all 2 cells in the DGV are updated with the same data. It seems to me that the threads have mixed up.

What might be the possible reason of having the same value of data from these 2 threads? Is it because of multiple threads that I have made here?

Comment: what does `getMarketData` do, how/where is the dgv updated?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Not all controls are nice enough to throw that exception for you whenever you mutate them.  DGV, for example, doesn't throw any exceptions when you mutate it's data source.  That doesn't mean it works, it just means that it doesn't tell you (in the form of an exception) that it won't work.

Comment: It is not possible to suggest why your code is not producing results you expect with sample you've provided. So far following things are wrong - likely updating UI control from non-UI thread, possibly using static (or simply the same) variables to store data....

Comment: @Servy - did not know that such common control as DGV does not verify caller's thread... Indeed does not change the fact that (not shown) code is likely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be accessing a DGV from any thread other than the UI thread.  Being a UI control it is specifically designed to only be accessed from the UI thread.